# What tag should we use for questions relating to developing/designing smart contracts?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

This category seems to make up a large but distinct portion of the questions here. So far I have seen:

- [smartcontract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartcontract)
- [contract-design](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-design)
- [dapps](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dapps)
- [debugging](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging)

Example question: [How do I program BTC Relay into my dapp?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/170/how-do-i-program-btc-relay-into-my-dapp)

Personally, I'm in favor of standardizing [contract-design](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-design) as the de-facto tag for the whole category.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest:

- [smart-contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-contracts) for general questions on smart contracts.
- [contract-design](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-design), [contract-debugging](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-debugging) and [contract-development](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-development) for special issues while creating smart contracts.
- [dapp](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dapp) for anything broader on the concept of decentralized apps.
- remove [debugging](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging) and [development](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development) in favour of the more specialized tags mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I generally agree with your suggestion, buy we may continue to get a variety of those tags.  Thanks for using my example - lol.

Comment: In that case, you can make some synonyms of the tags that often get used instead of the canonical tag. Say [tag:smartcontract] is a simple example of a [tag:dapps], you map [tag:smartcontract] as a synonym of [tag:dapps]. Then when someone tries to apply [tag:smartcontract] it is changed to [tag:dapps] automatically.

Answer (score 2):

The use of [contract-design](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-design) and [contract-development](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-development) seems to be more appropriate for the development of a smart contract. And I make a suggestion: We can use [contract-development](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-development) also to refer the debug, so in that way we delete the [debugging](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging) tag currently working in the site.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a distinct category of things that we will probably keep running into. In my industry we call the peocess of making third-party widgets talk to each "Integration" so when there is a clear purpose in someone's question where they take a component like BTCRelay, or Maker's DAI stablecoin, I would think a tag like "Contract-Integration" would fit quite nicely.

Integration I feel is distinct from debugging, because there may be nothing wrong yet tbat needs fixing. You just might need some documentation explained more clealry for you to proceed. I also expect the most common pieces of infrastructure (Coin API, NameReg, etc.) to end up with canonical answers for how to integrate them with you custom contract.

So, specifically for a question like the example linked, I would suggest the tag "Contract-Integration".